# RSS get First Five Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rss

I'm working with MVC, using RSS to get feed from wired.com . But I need not all feed, I need just first five feed . How can I do this?

```
        WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
        string RSSData = wclient.DownloadString("https://www.wired.com/feed/rss");
        return View();

        Document xml = XDocument.Parse(RSSData);
        var RSSFeedData = (from x in xml.Descendants("item")
                           select new RSSFeed
                           {
                               Title = ((string)x.Element("title")),
                               Link = ((string)x.Element("link"))
                           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Enumerable.Take(int). 
Returns a specified number of elements

```
IEnumerable<RSSFeed> RSSFeedData = (from x in xml.Descendants("item")
                           select new RSSFeed
                           {
                               Title = ((string)x.Element("title")),
                               Link = ((string)x.Element("link"))
                           }).Take(5);
```

here documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx